# Android OS Porting

Tags: android, porting

I am now reading the Android SW arch from this link http://developer.android.com/images/system-architecture.jpg

Suppose I need to have Android support in a brand new IC, is that I need to do the porting on LINUX KERNEL and APPLICATION FRAMEWORK? And for LIBRARIES, do I need to port it?

Also, for APPLICATION FRAMEWORK, what I think is the APPLICATION FRAMEWORK that show in the link is only for mobile phone, different product can have different APPLICATION FRAMEWORK. Am I right?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Start here:  [Android Platform Developer's Guide - Porting](http://source.android.com/porting/index.html) wherein the highest level steps are:

1. Port Android platform software to your hardware.
2. Comply with Android Compatibility Definition Document (CDD)
3. Pass the Compatibility Test Suite (CTS)

If your platform is x86-based, it has already been done by the [Android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) project.